# Understanding glm and link functions: how to generate data?

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, random-generation, link-function

I'm trying to take the approach for understanding how certain concepts work, by trying to generate data for them and checking how the output behaves. Currently, I thus realized I don't quite get what's going on with GLM-s.

Here is my little code:

```
N = 10000
e = rnorm(N,0,1)
x1 = runif(N,10,30)
y = exp(5*x1+ 10 + e)
mod1 = glm (y ~ x1,family=gaussian(link="log"))
mod2 = lm(log(y) ~ x1)
```

Calling summary of the models quickly reveals, that `mod2` is a nice fit, while `mod1` is bonkers. I tried brushing up on the topic, and many pages talk of transforming the mean of `y`, because `y` is not normally distributed, but I never really understood this, since the assumption of normality is for the residuals, not $y$, which is quite logical otherwise $y = mx +b $ would never work with $x$ sampled uniformly.

So I have two questions:

- What am I not getting here?
- How would I generate data that is valid for the above GLM?

### EDIT

I reformulated the code, to reflect more closely the mathematical background (based on Glen_b's answer I realized my way of adding the error doesn't work for all cases).

```
x = seq(from = 1,to = 15,by = 0.1)
N = length(x)
eta = 5*x + 10

# original
set.seed(5671)

y = exp(eta) + rnorm(N,0,1)
mod = glm(y ~ x,gaussian(link = "log"))

# new
set.seed(5671)

inverse_link = function(x){exp(x)}
means = sapply(eta,function(x){inverse_link(x)})
y = sapply(means,function(x){rnorm(1,mean=x,sd=1)})
mod = glm(y ~ x,gaussian(link = "log"))
```

The results can be compared to be the same in both cases. Based on this my expectation was that the following code can fit my parameters properly:

```
x = seq(from = 1,to = 15,by = 0.1)
N = length(x)
eta = 5*x + 10

set.seed(5671)

inverse_link = function(x){1/x}
scale = 1
shapes = sapply(eta,function(x){inverse_link(x)/scale})

y = sapply(shapes,function(x){rgamma(1,shape=x,scale=scale)})
mod = glm (y ~ x,family=Gamma(link="inverse"))
```

My reasoning was that $\mu = k\theta = 1/\eta$ so I need a gamma distribution with shape parameter $k = 1/\eta/\theta$. My problem is that this was, the coefficients are wildly off (~1.6 for $x$ and ~6.4 for intercept). Is it just my input data, or did I miss something?

#### EDIT 2

As pointed out in the gamma distribution the $k$, the shape parameter is kept constant (as far as I understand GLM assumes that the distributions used are from the natural exponential family, based on [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/184158/dispersion-parameters-in-glm) answer and gamma is that with a fixed shape parameter). So we have

$$y \sim \Gamma(k,\frac{1}{k\eta})$$

Here is the corrected code that now works:

````
x = seq(from = 1,to = 15,by = 0.1)
N = length(x)
eta = 5*x + 10

set.seed(5671)

inverse_link = function(x){1/x}
shape = 3
scales = sapply(eta,function(x){inverse_link(x)/shape})

y = sapply(scales,function(x){rgamma(1,shape=shape,scale=x)})
mod = glm (y ~ x,family=Gamma(link="inverse"))
summary(mod)
```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how to generate from a glm (the order of some items can be moved):

1. Choose your family and link function.
2. choose your predictors (IV's) for each observation you want to simulate.
3. Choose your coefficients.
4. Evaluate the linear predictor for each observation.
5. Transform by the inverse of the link function to get the conditional mean for each observation.
6. Choose any other parameters.
7. Sample the distribution at each observation, for which you now have all the parameters.

---

Let's see how to simulate a simple Gamma GLM with inverse link, following those steps:

1. Choose your family and link function. (*Gamma, inverse*)
2. choose your predictors (IV's) for each observation you want to simulate. ($x$)
3. Choose your coefficients.  (*choose a specific $\beta_0$ & $\beta_1$* in this case)
4. Evaluate the linear predictor for each observation. ($\eta_i=\beta_0+\beta_1 x_i,\: i=1,...,n$)
5. Transform by the inverse of the link function to get the conditional mean for each observation. (inverse of $\eta_i=1/\mu_i$ is $\mu_i=1/\eta_i$)
6. Choose any other parameters. (Choose the shape parameter)
7. Sample the distribution at each observation, for which you now have all the parameters. (e.g. `y=rgamma(length(x),shape,scale=mu/shape)` -- noting that `scale` is a vector of values here)

Comment: Your answer prompted me to reformulate the code to reflect the mathematics more closely (and also because I think my original formulation is pretty much restricted to the Gaussian family). I tried applying it to a gamma distribution though and it failed miserably :(

Comment: Note that the parameterization you're using in a Gamma glm is actually a mean-shape parameterization and the shape should be identical for every observation (the mean and hence the scale vary). You may need to review how glms work.

Comment: I am accepting this answer, because although it didn't actually correct the code, it explained the general process, while my original formulation was a bit restricted.

Comment: I couldn't simply correct your code since you were trying to generate a model by varying the shape parameter and fixing the scale. Given the need to model the mean and fix the shape parameter, you needed to completely reformulate your model; I didn't want to choose your new model for you.  I have written a more detailed recipe for a gamma glm with inverse link. By sticking (mostly) to not explicitly writing R code it should help people using other programs than R.

Comment: Thank you, I agree, this way it is more useful to other people.

Answer (score 3):

It matters whether the error term is included in the `exp()` call or not.  That's your big issue for this code.  Consider this:

```
#  first, set the random seed, so that everything is reproducible
set.seed(5671)
N  = 10000
e  = rnorm(N,0,1)
x1 = runif(N,10,30)
y1 = exp(5*x1+ 10  + e)
y2 = exp(5*x1+ 10) + e
mod1.1 = glm(y1 ~ x1,family=gaussian(link="log"))
mod1.2 = lm(log(y1) ~ x1)

mod2.1 = glm(y2 ~ x1,family=gaussian(link="log"))
mod2.2 = lm(log(y2) ~ x1)
```

Comment: When using `y = exp(5*x1+ 10) + e`, then the `glm` will not even converge after 25 iterations, while `mod2` is just bad (the latter I understand, since the residuals will not be normally distributed).

Comment: Sorry, yeah setting the seed is quite crucial here :) Only looking at `mod1.1` and `mod2.1`, if I check the `deviance residuals`, in both cases I get insane numbers, e.g for the medians respectively: `-1.116e+45` and `1.393e+34` which seems to suggest something is still wrong (or I don't really understand what these numbers are). Although I have to agree, the fit seems perfect in the second case.

Comment: @fbence, you're right about the convergence. It's fitting fine WRT the coefficients, but it's having trouble with the dispersion parameter (the residual SD). I'm not sure what the issue is.  It looks like we need to use a different optimizer.

Comment: What I don't really understand, is that whatever optimizer we use, calculating the error based on the good fitted parameters (which is the case here, since we have 5 and 9.9999 for the $\beta$ and $b$) should be very small, no?

Comment: I don't follow you, @fbence. The error between the fitted & true parameter values are very small.

Comment: Hmm, isn't the deviance residuals related to the difference between my actual values and the values predicted from the model? Because in that case there are some huge numbers flying around here.